# Tree view header inside add the dropdown menu in odoo 8 using js and python

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo, odoo-8

### Tree view header inside add the dropdown menu in odoo 8 using js and python

---

I am use odoo-8. My question is how to add the dropdown menu above side on tree view in odoo8 using JS and python.

And I want to dynamically show the all the category of products in this drop-down menu.

And when i click on the particular category so, tree view inside sort particular clickable types of products.

**i.e**

> Suppose click on the `Mobile` category from drop-down menu so tree view inside show only `Mobile` types of products.

Like I give the example in below image,
[image]

I want to full solution of this question.
**Note: If any query so comment please.**

Comment: Have you created template for drop down list already?

Comment: yes mr. vishal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **t-extend** in your **template.xml** code.

ControlPanel is template name of the controlpanel that placed above tree view.

Add this code inside of your template.xml code.

```
<t t-name="your_template_name" t-extend="ControlPanel">
    <t t-jquery=".o_cp_right" t-operation="after">
        <-- Add your Drop down list here -->
    </t>
</t>
```

**o_cp_right** is class after that you can add your dropdown field. You can set **t-operation** as append, inner, after, replace as per your requirment.

Comment: Mr.vishal good but your answer is wrong. you not understand my question.

Comment: my menu add in the default tree view not my template and odoo default tree view create using JS.

Comment: It means you want to add python selection field over there? or you want to add dropdown menu that you have created using js?

Comment: Yes i want all product categories in this drop-down and i don't have any field in python for this drop-down. I want to take it from product.category model.

Comment: You can use this code inside your existing template and also add field using it.

Comment: the above one!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147463/discussion-between-er-ceo-vora-mayur-and-vishal-khichadiya).